# Fluent Python example 2.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split, slice

In the book Fluent Python by L. Ramalho example 2.11 I encountered the following line of code ...

```
    line_items = invoice.split("\n") [2:]
```

with invoice being ...

```
    invoice = """
    line0
    line1
    line2
    """
```

I understand what the code does ... but I'm astounded that after 
line_items = invoice.split("\n") a slicing operation [2:] is permitted. Can someone explain to me why this represents valid code since [2:] does not appear to be a separate parameter of .split("\n").

Thank you ...

Answer (score 1):

That syntax is valid because `split` returns a list. The `[2:]` is slicing that returned list.